# How do I release the data from a DBAL query but not fetched without closing the database connection?

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.6, symfony-2.8, dbal

I'm using DBAL in Symfony version 2.8 and PHP to query data from my database, but after I get the results and no longer need them I want to release the data that may be cached and waiting form me to retrieve it.

```
    // I've already opened the database connection somewhere before this code is executed.

    $s = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable;';
    $conn = $this->get( 'database_connection' );
    $query = $conn->executeQuery( $s );
    $data = $query->fetch();

    // At this point $data contains a row from the database or is FALSE.

    unset( $data, $query ); // This will tell php that I don't need these variables.
```

There could be lots of rows of cached data waiting to be retrieved from the database server, taking up resources that I'd rather not waste.  How can I release the unfetched query data?

I don't want to close the database connection, because I will be using it to run this or other queries until the user logs out of my web-app or the session times out.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to call `$data->closeCursor()` before unset?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no.  I didn't see that in the DBAL documentation that I have, but trying $data->closeCursor() as you suggest produces: 'Error: Call to a member function closeCursor() on array' because $data is documented to be either false or the value(s) retrieved from the database, an array in my case, because I'm querying for multiple columns.  However, $query->closeCursor() doesn't error.

Comment: Just to be clear, (thanks again) Alessandro Chitolina's comment about using the closeCursor function to release the unread data cached on the server does not close the database connection, which I didn't want to do, when it closes the database cursor.  Also, calling closeCursor does not produce an error even when an explicit cursor has NOT been created.  See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/ on one way to explicitly create a cursor.  Using only the code shown in my question, doesn't explicitly do this.  Finally, in my code the correct way to make this call is $query->closeCursor();

Comment: Alessandro Chitolina, I'll give you credit for the solution if if you post it as a solution.  Otherwise, I'll post my own that references you and your answer, but I'll get the credit. :(

Comment: I posted the answer. Thank you Howard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments of the original post

```php
$query->closeCursor()
```

can be used to allow DBAL (and underlying connections) to release memory occupied by the pending data without closing the connection.